# Dealing with escape sequences with ReadOnlySpan<char>

Tags: c#, parsing, system.memory

The `ReadOnlySpan<char>` is said to be perfect for parsing so I tried to use it and I came across a use case that I don't know how to handle.

---

I have a command-line `string` where the argument prefix `-` and the separator  (space) are escaped *(I know I could quote them here but for the sake of this problem let's assume it's not an option)*:

```
 var str = @"foo -bar \-baz\ qux".AsMemory();
```

The tokenizer should return the following tokens:

1. `foo` - command name
2. `bar` - argument name
3. `-baz qux` - argument value

Cases `1` & `2` are simple because here I can just use `str.Slice(i, length)` but how can I create the `3rd` case and return only a single `ReadOnlySpan<char>`? The `Slice` method doesn't allow me to specify multiple `start/length` ranges which would be necessary in order to *jump over* the escape char `\`.

Example:

> ```
> str.Slice((10, 4), (15, 3));
> ```

where `(10,4) = "-bar"` and `(15,3) = " qux"`

With `StringBuilder` you can just skip a couple of characters and `Append` the others later. How would I achieve the same result with `ReadOnlySpan<char>`?

Comment: *The Slice method doesn't allow me to specify multiple start/length ranges* i don't quite understand what you mean here. can you explain a little? Also, using span here seems like hitting a fly with a sledge hammer, sure if you want to decrees allocations span and memory are awesome, but this is only a command line arg, and you are seemingly going to have to traverse the the span anyway.

Comment: @TheGeneral _using span here seems like hitting a fly with a sledge hammer_ - I know - in this case this might be true BUT the `Sytem.Memory` package is pretty new and you have start somehow so I picked a very simple use case to work with so let's forget for a moment that there are other ways ;-) By multiple `start/lengh` I mean something like this `str.Slice((10, 4), (15, 3));` where `(10,4) = "-bar"` and `(15,3) = " qux"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Span/ReadOnlySpan` is a contiguous block of memory. It cannot contain multiple ranges. This design is necessary for performance. `Span/ReadOnlySpan` is supposed to be roughly as fast as an array is. Arrays are fast because they are contiguous memory blocks with no further abstractions.

I don't see a way to do this without allocating a new string. You can use `Span/ReadOnlySpan` for all contiguous substrings but it seems your parsing problem is not suitable to use span to store results.

Comment: You write about `Span`, but the question is about `ReadOnlySpan`. For `ReadOnlySpan`, your answer is correct. If you do want to mention `Span`, there is another option: modify the buffer in-place.

Comment: @hvd in place writes are a good point although it seems very unsafe to modify a string in place. Who knows what that breaks. He could use a `char[]`.

Comment: @hvd @usr so I guess parsing anything that involves escape sequences (html, json, csv... etc. etc) cannot be done by using `System.Memory`, right?

Comment: Parsing is often made easier or more efficient. Storing the *results* of parsing is another matter. You are right in that escape sequences make using Span here impossible.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at:
https://github.com/nemesissoft/Nemesis.TextParsers

and more precisely at:
[TokenSequence.cs](https://github.com/nemesissoft/Nemesis.TextParsers/blob/master/Nemesis.TextParsers/TokenSequence.cs)

Usage:

```
var tokens = "ABC|CD\|E".AsSpan().Tokenize('|', '\\', false); //no allocation. Result in 2 elements: "ABC", "CD\|E".
```

Consume via:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var part in tokens)
     result.Add(part.ToString());
```

Unescaping can be done via:
[ParsedSequence.cs](https://github.com/nemesissoft/Nemesis.TextParsers/blob/master/Nemesis.TextParsers/ParsedSequence.cs)
or

```
SpanParserHelper.UnescapeCharacter()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Cool! I'll take a look ;-)

Comment: this is also available via nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nemesis.TextParsers/